Are logics-without-identity counterexamples to the apriority of the law of identity?
I proposed a hypothetical to my buddy:
Imagine a brain in a vacuum that exists with the necessary faculties to have conscious thought. This brain, however, is not connected to any sensory organs. If the brain has never experienced stimuli, then is it a leap to think the brain would be incapable of producing thought?
Obviously, this is contingent on the theory of mind we're using, and more of a causal deterministic lens.
But that got me thinking about apriori knowledge. Is conscious thought a necessary condition for apriori knowledge?
If apriori knowledge is defined as - experience-independent knowledge; and thoughts are contingent on experience, then if it is required to think to know, it would follow that apriori knowledge wouldn't exist.
We conceived of an argument to refute this:

P1) The human brain has the faculties to reason.


P2) Reasoning is governed by a set of rules, which entails the law of identity.


C1) The law of identity is a necessary faculty of reason.


P3) The law of identity is knowledge.


C2) Therefore, apriori knowledge can exist. (knowledge prior to experience.)

My response was that there may be more rules that spawn from our mental faculties, which might even contradict others. For example, non-contradiction & dialetheism.
My contention here was that there seem to be other logic systems that don't rely on the principle of identity. Ones that would go counter to the notion that the law of identity is evidence of apriori knowledge.
I'm interested to know what analysis of this topic there is that is current in the literature, and that you are familiar with.
Note I'm aware that there are similar questions, however none seem to ask the questions asked here in specificity. Please don't mark this as a duplicate.

No, not by themselves. The purposes of modern logics are much broader than expressing "the faculties of reason" or "the laws of thought", be they a priori or otherwise. We may well be interested in logics that do not reflect how we actually reason just as we are interested in arithmetics and geometries that do not reflect how we count or measure things, respectively. See SEP, Logical Pluralism.

@KristianBerry I appreciate the modifications, I honestly was so tired I couldn’t think of a better way to word the title.
